# css not showing inline

Tags: html, css

The way I like for my code to displayed is

```
Name1      
Name2 Jim
```

The way it is doing now is:

```
Name1 Name2  Jim
```

How can I change it so that it looks like the way I want it to?

CSS

```
.display-left {
     float: left; 
     width: 200px; 
     text-align: left; 
     font-weight:bold   
}

.display-right {
     text-align: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="display-left">Name1:   </div>
  <div class="display-right" > </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="display-left">Name2: </div>
  <div class="display-right">Jim </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you considered using a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to add a `clear:left;` to your `.display-left` class. And a `float:left;` to your display-right class

http://jsfiddle.net/f5cUx/3/

```
.display-left {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight:bold;
    clear:left;
}

.display-right {
    text-align: left;
    float:left; 
}
```

The ["clear" property](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clear) specifies on which sides other floating elements are not allowed.

I also just noticed you had wrapped each "row" in a div. In that case you could just put a new class on those "wrapper" divs that clears the float.

http://jsfiddle.net/f5cUx/4/

Comment: Jim is in the wrong place though, it is above where it should be.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev - +1. Much better :)

Answer (score 0):

if you add:
    display: block;
to your .display-left class, it would probably work. try it on!

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:block` to `.display-right;` . This tells the HTML to say "please take up the whole line" . You could use `<br>` tags, but this would be good only for one example. After that it is a waste of code

You can also try adding `clear:both;` to `display-right` 
 This tells the HTML to say "break out of the float and always stay below  the float"

Answer (score -1):

put a `<br>` in your html after name1 but before name2 this should do what you want or try `<p></p`

Comment: This is a very unconventional way of doing this. If you had 1000 of these, that's is a lot of unneeded code